# How to avoid duplication of dependency declaration in a Clojure/ClojureScript project?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen, shadow-cljs, deps-edn

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, re-frame, reagent, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Currently, dependencies are being declared on `project.clj`, on `shadow-cljs.edn`, and on `deps.edn`.

0 -  I would like to **ditch** `deps.edn`

1 - I would like to avoid [Boot](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot) and optimize for `lein`

2 - I would like to *avoid duplication of dependency declaration*.
**Ideally, I would like to have the dependencies all declared just in one file, maybe with a pointer in the other!** If not possible in just one file, use two - without `deps.edn`.

(i) - Dependencies on `project.clj`:

```clj
  :dependencies
  [[org.clojure/clojure        "1.11.1"]
   [org.clojure/tools.logging  "1.2.4"]
   [org.clojure/clojurescript  "1.11.60"]
   [reagent                    "0.10.0"]
   [re-frame                   "0.12.0"]
   [garden                     "1.3.10"]
   [metosin/malli              "0.8.4"]
   [metasoarous/oz             "1.6.0-alpha35"]

   [hiccup                      "1.0.5"]] ; html parsing and manipulation
```

(ii) - Dependencies on `shadow-cljs.edn`:

```clj
 :dependencies
 [[reagent "1.1.0"]
  [re-frame "1.2.0"]
  [day8.re-frame/tracing "0.6.2"]
  [garden "1.3.10"]
  [metosin/malli "0.8.3"]

  [binaryage/devtools "1.0.3"]
  [day8.re-frame/re-frame-10x "1.1.11"]]
```

(iii) - Dependencies on `deps.edn`:

```clj
{:deps
 {org.clojure/clojure {:mvn/version "1.10.3"},
  reagent {:mvn/version "0.10.0"},
  org.clojure/tools.logging {:mvn/version "1.1.0"},
  org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.866"}, 
  ring {:mvn/version "1.9.0"}, 
  garden {:mvn/version "1.3.10"}, 
  metosin/malli {:mvn/version "0.5.1"}, 
  hiccup {:mvn/version "1.0.5"}, 
  metasoarous/oz {:mvn/version "1.6.0-alpha35"}, 
  re-frame {:mvn/version "0.12.0"}}

 :source-paths ["src" "test"]}
```

How would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I do recommend keeping your CLJS dependencies in `shadow-cljs.edn` and your CLJ dependencies in `project.clj`. It avoids a couple pitfalls and footguns. It is fine to keep everything in `project.clj` though, just need to be careful to avoid some mistakes.

You change your `shadow-cljs.edn` to add [`:lein true`](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#Leiningen) but remove `:dependencies` and `:source-paths` completely. You then add all the `:dependencies` that aren't already in `project.clj` and in addition add `thheller/shadow-cljs` (latest version `"2.20.10"`). Thats it.

When doing this you must make sure not to introduce dependency conflicts in the future. So, a common problem is trying to update `shadow-cljs` but keeping an older `clojurescript` version, or vice versa. The problem of doing this is that `shadow-cljs` will inherit all the CLJ dependencies of your CLJ side, which may or may not cause conflicts/problems when trying to run shadow-cljs. These are all solveable problems, but problems you need to solve since `shadow-cljs` no longer can. It only can when dependencies are managed via `shadow-cljs.edn`.

You may also opt to move the CLJS dependencies into a lein alias if you want. You then change the `shadow-cljs.edn` to `:lein {:aliases [:cljs]}` (or whatever alias you choose).